# Problem with creating a record in the database

Tags: python, mysql

There is a code:

```
self.data = self.handle.execute("INSERT INTO {} (`{}`, `{}`, `{}`, `{}`, `{}`) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(
        TABLES['day_statictics'],
        ROWS['day_statictics_date'],
        ROWS['day_statictics_all'],
        ROWS['day_statictics_arz'],
        ROWS['day_statictics_oth'],
        ROWS['day_statictics_all_reg'],
        now.strftime ('%d-%m-%Y'),
        data['all'],
        data['arz'],
        data['ost'],
        data['all_us']
    ))
```

His result:

```
INSERT INTO `day_statictics` (`date`, `all_s`, `arizona`, `other`, `all_reg_user`) VALUES ('29-06-2021', '661', '412', '249', '13953')
```

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNhRy.png)

There are no errors in the request, it is executed via regular SQL(mysql web function). At the same time, if you enter it manually, the id in mysql immediately goes from 1 to 7. It turns out that the request passes, the id is shifted, but there is no record. What to do?

Comment: what id?  edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table day_statistics`

Comment: are you hoping to update an existing record instead of adding a new one?

Comment: No, im edited, try again

Comment: please add the create table, that date looks funny as mysql saves its dates in yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: what id?  what do you mean shifted?  what record is there not?

Comment: The first id is 2, the second is already 7, see? There is no error in the request, the record should be created, its id is engaged, but there is no record itself